# Accept string input for attribute, store integer in DB, return string in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-api

I am building a rails api app. I have an Animal class

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = { herbivore: 1, carnivore: 2, omnivore: 3 }
  attr_reader :name, :type
end
```

In DB, I am saving the values for type as integers 1, 2, 3.

In the controller, the create action accepts type as "herbivore", "carnivore" or "omnivore"

```
#POST animals
Request:  { name: "tommy", type: "carnivore" }
Response: { id: 1 }, status: 204
```

Similarly, the show action responds with  "herbivore", "carnivore" or "omnivore"

```
#GET animals/1
Response: { id: 1, name: "tommy", type: "carnivore" }, status: 200
```

To achieve what I want, I have added these methods in my Animal class

```
def type=(value)
 super(TYPES[value.to_sym])
end

def type
  TYPES.key(read_attribute(:type))
end
```

And this works fine.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), like this:

```rb
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum type: [ :herbivore, :carnivore, :omnivore ]
end
```